# Only load full video for specific screen resolution

Tags: html, html5-video

I have 3 videos for 3 different screen resolutions. I want to load the specific video for the shown resolution on page load and avoid loading the rest. Only 1 of 3 should be loaded.

For ios (using safari), autoplay needs to be present on page load for the videos to be shown without the controls. Even if I remove the autoplay attribute on page load, the entire video is being loaded.

On desktop, if I add autoplay after page load, the videos aren't being fully loaded.

How can I get only the videos which are visible to be fully loaded on page load?

Here's a simple example of the code:

```html
<div>
    <video muted="" class="col-md-12 d-none d-lg-block" poster="">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="/video_Large.mp4">
      </video>
    <video muted="" class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none" poster="">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="/video_Medium.mp4">
      </video>
    <video autoplay muted="" class="d-block d-md-none" poster="">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="/uploads/video_Small.mp4">
      </video>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to play a different video for a different screen resolution?

Comment: @liakoyras correct, only one of these 3 videos will be shown at a time. I want to preload the one that is shown.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add id tags like this in your HTML:

```
<video id="large" muted="" class="col-md-12 d-none d-lg-block" poster="">
   <source type="video/mp4" src="/video_Large.mp4">
</video>
<video id="medium" muted="" class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none" poster="">
   <source type="video/mp4" src="/video_Medium.mp4">
</video>
<video id="small" autoplay muted="" class="d-block d-md-none" poster="">
   <source type="video/mp4" src="/uploads/video_Small.mp4">
</video>
```

Then you need to make your css responsive and hide the other two videos for each screen size. For example,

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    #small, #medium{ 
        display: none;
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid the entirety of the video being preloaded when the page loads, you can add `preload="none"` or `preload="metadata"` attribute to the video tags. This means that the video will play only when the user clicks on it.

Comment: The drawback of this approach is that the browser is likely to preload **all** the videos, which is really inefficient.

Comment: You are certainly right. However I think that this could help a beginner out by pointing out different ways to work with html/css.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to avoid the issue @Quentin is pointing out.

Comment: https://surfthedream.com.au/writing/disable-preloading-on-html5-videos/
This page describes how to use the preload attribute in order to avoid this issue.